# Check if an array value exist

Tags: php

```
$city = $_GET['cityselect'];
add_query_arg( array ( 'city' => $city, 'key' => 'value' );
```

Basically i want to check if $city exists and if not i want to remove both key and value, ie `'city' => $city,` (comma included). So the output would be:

```
add_query_arg( array ( 'key' => 'value' );
```

Any idea?

Comment: Try to google for "PHP key exists".

Comment: Why -1 this? I already search for a solution but none worked. Also nickb's answer is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only add the `city` key if it is set, like this:

```
$arg = array( 'key' => 'value');

if( isset( $_GET['cityselect'])) 
    $arg['city'] = $_GET['cityselect'];

add_query_arg( $arg);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$data = array();
if(isset($_GET["cityselect"])){
 $data["city"] = $_GET["cityselect"];
}

add_query_arg($data); // ..
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're attempting to remove `city` if it doesn't exist, you could do:

```
$city = isset($_GET['cityselect']) ? $_GET['cityselect'] : null;
if (empty($city)) unset($yourArray['city']);
```

This assumes you already have an array, `$yourArray`, pre-defined with a `city` index.

I would recommend to only insert the `city` index after you've verified it though, such as:

```
if (isset($_GET['cityselect']) && !empty($_GET['cityselect'])) {
    $yourArray['city'] = $_GET['cityselect'];
}
```

**UPDATE:** You could also use [`array_filter()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to remove all indexes with missing values after you're done populating it:

```
$yourArray = array_filter($yourArray);
```

This will return an array with all empty values stripped; In your case, if `city` is empty it will be removed from the array.

Answer (score 0):

For the short but ugly one-liner version:

`add_query_arg($args = (!empty($_GET['cityselect'])) ? array('city' => $_GET['cityselect'], 'key' => 'value') : array('key' => 'value');`

Slightly more elegant:

```
if(!empty($_GET['cityselect']))
    add_query_arg(array('city' => $_GET['cityselect'], 'key' => 'value'));
else
    add_query_arg(array('key' => 'value'));
```

Have assumed use of `empty`, but substitute for `isset` if applicable to your circumstances.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [array_search()](http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) (Searches the array for a given value and returns the corresponding key if successful).

Comment: Ah, I thought the array key was unknown, disregard this answer.